# Modifying the size of my Linux partition

Tags: 16.04, boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows

I recently purchased a new laptop (Blade Pro) and am dual booting Windows 10 with Ubuntu 16.04. I made a decision to give roughly 40gb of space to the Linux partition, but recently I have come to the realisation I urgently need to increase this size.

As you know, installing Ubuntu on a Blade is an incredibly annoying process with many places where it can go wrong, so I'm really hoping I will not need to re-do this process.

Is there a way I can swap around 40gb from my Windows partition over to Ubuntu? Ideally with no settings/files affected, but if I lose stuff on the Windows side it doesn't matter too much. On Ubuntu I have spent countless hours getting CUDA, and other GPU stuff to work, so would rather not have to re-do this.

I saw on a related post that I should give the output of `sudo fdisk -l`, so here it is:

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 0361E93B-1291-4E2F-A5C6-8DC95F5DE68F

Device             Start        End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048   24578047  24576000 11.7G Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p2  24578048   24782847    204800  100M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p3  24782848   24815615     32768   16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p4  24815616  876310527 851494912  406G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p5 999190528 1000214527   1024000  500M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p6 876310528  965859327  89548800 42.7G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p7 965859328  999190527  33331200 15.9G Linux swap

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Using a Windows-based tool shrink `nvme0n1p4`, which probably appears as `C:` in Windows. Shutdown Windows (remember to disable fast boot aka fake shutdown), then boot from the Linux installation media into a live session. Run Gparted. You will find some free space before `nvme0n1p6`. Using Gparted move and extend this partition.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Do I shrink `nvme0n1p4` from the Windows side? What is a live session? Apologies for the questions.

Comment: Yes, it's best to shrink Windows partitions from the Windows side. A live session is what you get when you boot from the Ubuntu installation medium and choose "Try Ubuntu"; it's a full Ubuntu environment but running from the installation medium and not from your fixed disk, so that you can (in this specific case) use Gparted on the fixed disk.

Comment: Yes shrink from Windows side and a live session simply means plugin your Ubuntu usb and choose `try Ubuntu`, and when that is up run `gparted` then move the partitions as needed.

Comment: @AlexP I would think using a `gparted livecd` would be ok too?

Comment: Thank you, I'll give this a go. Is there anything to worry about to do with different filesystems, ntfs fat32 etc? Or it shouldn't affect anything? Any advice on what program to use in Windows to shrink its partition, and is this safe to do from Windows (as it seems its not safe to modify Linux's partition whilst in ubuntu)?

Comment: You can do it from the Control Panel. Read this: www.lifewire.com/how-to-open-disk-management-2626080 then shrink the big windows partition.

Comment: While it's great to know that something complex is within your reach, do recall that mucking about with partitions can be dangerous - there is a non-zero risk of TOTAL DATA LOSS. Good backups before starting is a wise idea.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Important data all backed up, and will commence the resizing process now! Fingers crossed, will get back with updates.

Comment: Pretty much went perfectly. A few problems with my bootable USB which also occurred when I first installed ubuntu, but rewriting the .iso a few times fixed it. I'll write up an answer to myself detailing all the steps shortly in case anyone's in a similar predicament as myself and comes along this post. Thanks a lot for the help everyone.